# Trying to understand some SQL Server change tracking features

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I'm working on SQL Server 2016 SP1 with the Change Tracking feature and I have a question for you.

I have a database which has Change Tracking enabled. That database contains a table `Table` which has "change tracking" activated, but not "track columns updated" option.

For the example, on `Table`, I only have one column called `Id` of type is "uniqueidentifier", which is my PK.

On start, my change tracking current version is 0.

I got it with :

```
SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();
```

I added a new row to `Table`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Table] (Id) 
VALUES ('C99F9E2A-1974-47CE-A406-481076F53BBD');
```

Now, my change tracking current version is now 1.

With this request, I can see my element in the change tracking system :

```
SELECT * 
FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES dbo.[Table], 0) CT;
```

The result is :

[image: result 1]

Now, I delete my row with this :

```
DELETE FROM dbo.[Table] 
WHERE Id = 'C99F9E2A-1974-47CE-A406-481076F53BBD';
```

Change tracking current version is now 2.

I insert it again with the same request than previous.

Change tracking current version is now 3.

With this request, I got this result :

```
SELECT * 
FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES dbo.[Table], 1) CT;
```

[image]

Now is my question, why I got "U" in SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION ?

Why not "I" cause 1 < SYS_CHANGE_CREATION_VERSION which is 3 ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding some motivation, the intent of the change tracking functions is to enable you to see what has changed since the last time you checked, *and* enable you to harvest and apply those changes to some other table or external system.

If you look at the changes since *just after* the delete you will see the operation as an `I`.  But if you look at the change since before the delete, you "skip over" the delete.  But change tracking doesn't remember what the non-key values were before the delete.  So the row is reported as having been updated.

EG

```
ALTER DATABASE current  
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)  
go
drop table if exists ct

create table ct(id uniqueidentifier primary key)

ALTER TABLE ct
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON) 

declare @beforeInsert bigint = (SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION());
INSERT INTO dbo.ct (Id) VALUES ('C99F9E2A-1974-47CE-A406-481076F53BBD');
declare @afterInsert bigint = (SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION());
DELETE FROM dbo.ct WHERE Id = 'C99F9E2A-1974-47CE-A406-481076F53BBD';
declare @afterDelete bigint = (SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION());
INSERT INTO dbo.ct (Id) VALUES ('C99F9E2A-1974-47CE-A406-481076F53BBD');


SELECT 'from before insert to current',id, sys_change_operation FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES dbo.ct, @beforeInsert) CT
union all
SELECT 'from after insert to current',id, sys_change_operation FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES dbo.ct, @afterInsert) CT
union all
SELECT 'from after delete to current',id, sys_change_operation FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES dbo.ct, @afterDelete) CT
```

outputs

```
                              id                                   sys_change_operation
----------------------------- ------------------------------------ --------------------
from before insert to current C99F9E2A-1974-47CE-A406-481076F53BBD I
from after insert to current  C99F9E2A-1974-47CE-A406-481076F53BBD U
from after delete to current  C99F9E2A-1974-47CE-A406-481076F53BBD I
```

Comment: oh sure, provide a nice example :-)           .

Answer (score 3):

From [Microsoft Docs CHANGETABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#changetablechanges)

> If you delete a row and then insert a row that has the old primary key, the change is seen as an update to all columns in the row.

Presumably, `id` is the primary key of the table in question.

Also, don't use `id` as the name of a column, use `TableID`... so if the table name is `Users`, then the primary key (if using a surrogate key) should be `UserID`.  Using `id` as the name of your primary key column makes for considerable confusion and makes your code error-prone.  Take a look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199234/10832) answer for details about that.

Comment: That's exactly what i was just thinking in my head. Although I'm not sure I fully agree with the last paragraph of your answer. I don't mind PK's names `ID` with FK's named `UserId`.

Comment: FWIW, I often see `Id` where an ORM is involved, as it enables OO code to work with entities generically.

Comment: Also `Id` plays nicer modeling subtypes.  So you don't end up like Adventureworks where `Sales.SalesPerson` has a PK of `BusinessEntityId`